# pg_restore with dockerized PostgreSQL ends in segmentation fault

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-restore

I am creating dumps on a dockerized PostgreSQL database on my server with following command:

```
docker exec -t postgres pg_dump -Fc -U mydb | gzip > $BACKUP_DIR/pg_db-mydb.gz
```

If I want to restore the backup I have tried different ways on my local machine (macOS) but it ends all in an segmentation fault error:

```
pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U user -d mydb -Fc pg_db-mydb
```

> segmentation fault  pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U myuser -d mydb -Fc

Also trying to copy the file into the PostgreSQL Docker container and then using `pg_restore` inside the container is given the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Get the core dump, create a stack trace and add it to the question. Install PostgreSQL debugging symbols to make the stack trace interesting.